# how do I connect some Strings in an array to another multiple array? (PHP, Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two different Arrays. The first array ($ecode) is a multiple array. The output of $ecode looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ecode] => 200
            [number] => 540
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ecode] => 404
            [number] => 44
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ecode] => 403
            [number] => 9
        )
)
```

(codes like 404, 200 .... are in there and the quantity ( [number] ) how much they exist in my log file )

in my seccond, normal array are just some strings:

```
$ecode_text[] = ['Document Not Found', 'Server busy', 'Forbidden', 'Request executed', '........' ];
```

My Problem is that I need to put the Strings to his right Error Code

like 404 not Found

at the end my multiple array should look like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ecode] => 204
                [number] => 540
                [text] => Request executed
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ecode] => 404
                [number] => 44
                [text] => Document not Found
)
```

Could anybody help me with this? I never have connected two different arrays and havent a clue where to start. In my google search I haven't found something realated to my problem.

I'm using Laravel Framework, normal php would be enough but if someone knows a solution in Laravel, this would be great.

Thanks for any help!

what I have tried:

```
$error_val = array_count_values($ecode_array);
foreach($error_val as $key => $val){
    $errors[] = [
        'number' => $val,
    ];
}

$ecode_text[] =
    [
        404 => 'Document Not Found',
        503 => 'Server busy',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        204 => 'Request executed',
        307 => 'Moved => temporarily',
        303 => 'Moved temporarily (redirect)',
        206 => 'Partial Content',
        301 => 'Moved permanently (redirect)',
        500 => 'Internal server Error'
        ];

foreach($ecode_text as $ecode => $test){
    if ($ecode == in_array($ecode, $errors)){
        $end_ecode[] = [
            'ecode' => $ecode,
            'test' => $test,
            'number' => $errors['number']
        ];
    }
}
```

but this wont work with me..

Comment: What you have tried so far. Post your attempts. As you can simply use `foreach` over here

Comment: well I tried something with array_merge but removed the things that I've tried.. There isnt anything I can show you but I really tried to find a solution. I'm more a PHP 'beginner'. Thats why i'm a little bit stucked in this problem

Comment: You have to know how the String arrays in B connect to A.  There isnt an error code at all or way to reference in B, and there is no comparitor to help determine how to merge the 2 arrays correctly.

Comment: but how do I say my foreach that "Document not found" belongs to 404, or "Request executed" belongs to 204? I think thats my biggest problem

Comment: you need your encode text to be an array of objects, so you will have a key (404) to use when merging

Comment: i updated my quesion.. can you look over it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have your normalized text refer to an error code, so build e.g. you array like this:

```
$ecode_text = [404 => 'Document Not Found', 403 => 'Server busy', 401 => 'Forbidden', '........' ];
```

and just `foreach` it

```
foreach ($ecode as &$e):
  $e['text'] = $ecode_text[$e['ecode']];
endforeach;
```

Comment: Your code is not really logic and doesn't work - what do you need more than my answer?